# for loop is not getting executed in python

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a command and store the result in a text file, that part of my code is working. Now i am trying to count the number of lines in the new text file created and decide if user id is valid/invalid.
Now the issue is my for loop is not working in my python,

**Here is a part of my code:**

```
   with open('USER_LIST', "r") as infile:
    for core_id in infile:
        filename = "%s.txt" %core_id.strip()
        subprocess.Popen("query", stdout=outfile , shell=True)
        count = 0
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            logger.info("inside for loop")
            count = count + 1
            if count < 15:
                invalid_id_file = "valid_id.txt"
                with open(invalid_id_file , "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(core_id)
```

My code never prints this line `"inside for loop"`. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: indentation matters - fix it. thanks

Comment: `filename` != `outfile`, so you may not be counting lines in the file you just created. Also, you determine the file after reading the first line and noticing that you haven't read 15 lines yet.

Comment: edited my code to include outfile part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the process that writes into a file to finish. Add:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("query", stdout=outfile , shell=True)
p.wait()
```